# What are unspeakable types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

I have read this article [What's new in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8) by Microsoft about new features in .NET 8 and faced the term *unspeakable types* here:

> Support for compiler-generated or unspeakable types in weakly typed
> source generation scenarios.

Please shed some light on what the term *unspeakable types* really means, if possible, with some examples.

Comment: this is the other name for the compiler generated types for example `<>c__DisplayClass1`

Comment: Search for "non-denotable types". These are types used by the compiler that you can't use in declarations in source code. In Java: https://openjdk.org/jeps/286

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik "unspeakable types" is just another name for "compiler generated" types, is that correct?

Comment: @user10025519 yup

Comment: Compiler-generated types are usually unspeakable, but not always. E.g. the compiler may generate a class based on a T4 text template. It's compiler generated but the name is based on the template file name so you can refer to it in your code. I think (not 100% sure) unspeakable means types that you can't refer to, e.g. anonymous types, closures, and structs used to store state in an async method. The compiler is generating these and has a unique name for each one, but the name is private, contains special characters, and it will never let you refer to them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Unspeakable" things just means that thing has a name that is not a valid C# identifier, and therefore you cannot "speak" of it in C#. It's not just limited to types - I've heard people use the term "unspeakable variable" too.

While C#'s identifiers has many restrictions, e.g. can't contain symbols, can't start with a digit, etc, IL doesn't have as many restrictions on names of things. This means that the compiler can implement language features by generating "helper" types and methods etc, without needing to worry about the programmer also declaring something with the same name and causing a conflict.

An example of this is how anonymous types are implemented. When you do:

```
var foo = new {
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2
};
```

`foo` is an instance of an unspeakable type. See this on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFADcCGAnABAMwPZ5YC8WAdgKYDuWA3slg1gGIHFZwA09jAQpmzGQBfANxA==) to find out what the unspeakable name is, or you can print out `foo.GetType()`. It usually contains symbols like `<` and `>`. If the compiler had generated a speakable name instead, like `AnonymousType1`, there would be a name conflict when your code also declares a type with that name!

Other features that are implemented using unspeakable types one way or another include: lambda expressions (for capturing variables), local methods (for capturing variables), `async` methods (for creating the state machine class), just to name a few off the top of my head.