# Refer to the properties of ancestors when instantiating and extending a class "in one shot"

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

Thanks to [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741235/overriding-virtual-methods-when-instantiating-a-class) I am able to override a virtual method in C# when I extend a class into a kind of anonymous type.

But is it possible to refer to a class variable or property of the ancestor class?

Here is a simplified version of my C# code:

```
public class MyAsyncBackgroundJob<TExecuteArgs> {

    public Func<TExecuteArgs, Task> ExecutePropAsync { get; set; }

    protected int _myVariable = 1;  // just an example
    public int MyProp { get; set; } = 2;  // just an example


    public MyAsyncBackgroundJob() {
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(TExecuteArgs args) {
        return ExecutePropAsync(args);
    }
}
```

And how I'd like to use it:

```
var myVar = new MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string> {
    ExecutePropAsync = (string s) => {
        string output = null;

        // this example works:
        if (s == "example") output = s + s;

        // this example DOESN'T works as compiler says _myVariable not found:
        if (_myVariable == 1) output = s + s;

        // this example DOESN'T works as compiler says MyProp not found
        if (MyProp == 1) output = s + s;

        return Task.FromResult(output);
    }
};

// Note: in the real life ExecuteAsync(TExecuteArgs args) is called automatically by the framework
await myVar.ExecutePropAsync("example");
```

Comment: There are no anonymous types anywhere in your code. You are creating an instance of `MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string>` (which clearly is not anonymous).

Comment: You’re right. I said it wrong: I wanted to say that I’m trying this code based on the idea of extending a class "on the fly": without explicitly defining it, but inspired by anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are wrong. The variable `anonymous` is not anonymous, it is strong typed as `MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string>`, but the lambda expression does indeed generate an anonymous type (more accurate: [an unspeakable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035964/what-are-unspeakable-types-in-c)).

Your problem is because you try to refer to the properties of `MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string>` within the scope of the lambda expression, Unlike within the scope of the class definition, there is no implicit `this` object in that scope, you must provide a reference of the object like `obj.MyProp`.

But when you use the object initializer like this: `var obj = new MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string>{}`, actually, this variable `obj` will only be assigned after the object initializer is completed, so you are not able to access it in the lambda expression. You can pre initialize it.

```
MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string> job = null;

job = new MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string> {
    ExecutePropAsync = (string s) => {
        string output = null;

        // this example works:
        if (s == "example") output = s + s;

        // this example DOESN'T works:
        //if (job._myVariable == 1) output = s + s;

        if (job.MyProp == 1) output = s + s;

        return Task.FromResult(output);
    }
};
```

However, no matter what, `job._myVariable` won't work, because you cannot access protected fields/properties outside the scope of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra parameter to `ExecutePropAsync`, so that you can pass `this` when calling it. Then at the use site, you can have access to `this` via that parameter.

```
public Func<MyAsyncBackgroundJob<TExecuteArgs>, TExecuteArgs, Task> ExecutePropAsync { get; init; }

public Task ExecuteAsync(TExecuteArgs args) {
    return ExecutePropAsync(this, args);
}
```

Now this compiles:

```
var job = new MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string> {
    ExecutePropAsync = (self, s) => {
        string output = null;
        if (s == "example") output = s + s;
        if (self.MyProp == 1) output = s + s;

        return Task.FromResult(output);
    }
};
```

However, this approach does not allow you to access protected members. After all, the lambda you assign to `ExecutePropAsync` is not in `MyAsyncBackgroundJob`, or any of its subclasses.

While you can also pass the protected properties you need as parameters of the lambda in the same way (perhaps wrap them in another class first, if there are many), I personally would just create a subclass of `MyAsyncBackgroundJob` at this point, which is more maintainable. Otherwise, you'd have to update the lambda parameters/properties in the wrapper class every time you add a protected member in `MyAsyncBackgroundJob`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing signature of `ExecutePropAsync` to accept two additional ints, which you can then pass when executing the method inside `MyAsyncBackgroundJob<TExecuteArgs>` class.

This way, you will be able to pass `_myVariable` and `MyProp` directly to method through parameters. And having parameters in the method, let's you use them inside it :)

Here's slightly refactored example of yours.

```
internal static class testarea
{
    internal static void Test()
    {
        var anonymous = new MyAsyncBackgroundJob<string>
        {
            ExecutePropAsync = (string s, int myVariable, int myProp) => {
                string output = null;

                if (s == "example") output = s + s;

                if (myVariable == 1) output = s + s;

                if (myProp == 1) output = s + s;

                return Task.FromResult(output);
            }
        };
    }
}

public class MyAsyncBackgroundJob<TExecuteArgs>
{

    public Func<TExecuteArgs, int, int, Task> ExecutePropAsync { get; set; }

    protected int _myVariable = 1;  // just an example
    public int MyProp { get; set; } = 2;  // just an example


    public MyAsyncBackgroundJob()
    {
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(TExecuteArgs args)
    {
        return ExecutePropAsync(args, _myVariable, MyProp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal, but behind all there is DI that populate `myProp`. Moreover the framework requires ExecuteProp parameters must be serializable and in my real case it's not an int. So your proposal cannot be used in my case